# A priori estimate for Yamabe solution 

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations

We know Schoen's compactness on Yamabe problem:

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a smooth compact Riemannian manifold of dimension
$3\leq n\leq 24$ without boundary. Denote $\Phi$ to be the full set
of arbitrary solutions for the Yamabe equation: 
$\Phi=\{\varphi>0|4\frac{n-1}{n-2}\Delta\varphi+S\varphi=Q_g(\varphi)\varphi^{\frac{n+2}{n-2}},\|\varphi\|_{\frac{2n}{n-2}}=1\}$.

If $(M^n,g)$ has positive Yamabe
quotient and is not conformally diffeomorphic to $(S^n,g_{std})$,then there exists a constant $C>0$ depending only on $g$ such that
$\frac{1}{C}\leq \varphi\leq C\quad \hbox{and} \quad\|\varphi\|_{C^{2,\alpha}}\leq C,\quad \forall \varphi \in \Phi.$

My question is that I want to estimate the constant $C$ more
precisely, or at least for the Yamabe minimizer? In other words,
under what assumption on the metric (such as Yamabe constant, Scalar
curvature bound, volume, etc), we have an estimate on the Yamabe
minimizer?

Further more, In the nonpositive Yamabe constant case, can we
estimate the unique solution for the Yamabe equation with the
information of the Scalar curvature bound (Not necessary
nonpositive), Yamabe constant, etc?

Comment: You mean the compactness result of Khuri, Marques and Schoen?

Comment: The Khuri-Marques-Schoen proof is by blowup arguments. It is general fact of life that arguments by blowup/contradiction don't give very explicit constants...

Comment: For the last question, you might benefit from Green's function estimates for Schrödinger type equations. Please let me know if you find something.